# Configure Perforce to require passwords for admin users?

Tags: perforce

Our Perforce server is set to [security level 0](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.security.html), meaning that most users don't require passwords. This is fine (and necessary for our legacy tools). However I recently discovered to my horror that some *admin* user accounts don't have passwords set. This is obviously very bad.

**How can we configure Perforce to require passwords for *superuser* accounts, but not for regular accounts?**

I seem to remember this was the case by default, but someone seems to have defeated it, and now I can't find any mention of it in the Perforce manual.

We **cannot** change the server to require passwords from *all* users without breaking the whole company. Setting [the server security level](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.security.html) to >1 globally is not a workable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this was never a feature.

My solution to this has historically been to have a script that tries to run a command as each user.  In your case you want to only look at users with admin-level permissions, so have the script run a command that only admins should be able to run:

```
p4 -u $USER protect -o
```

If this succeeds (despite the lack of any password being provided), deal with them as you like.  In my case I wasn't targeting admin users specifically so I just had my script set a random password and email it to them with instructions for changing it.

Given your scenario, my recommendation would be to just revoke admin access, since someone who's not savvy enough to secure their own account probably shouldn't be trusted with the ability to grant access to others, install triggers, permanently delete data, etc...

Comment: Thanks. I feel like I'm going daft - I have a clear memory of setting a password on my own account because that was required to switch it from regular to admin access (otherwise I wouldn't have a password myself).

Comment: Pretty sure the only requirement was your own good sense.  :) When you run "p4 protect" and add a `super user NAME * //...` line, user NAME doesn't even necessarily need to exist, much less have a password set.

Comment: Found the script FWIW -- I remembered wrong about the emailing part, I just had it lock them out (most of the users didn't have valid email addresses set in their user specs anyway) and let them get in touch if they wanted to restore access.  :) 
 https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/sam_stafford/scripts/pw_cleanup.pl